# I want to add a column only flat numbers without decimal

Tags: sql-server

My column data will be like this

```
1,
2,
1.02,
2.23,
5
```

I want to add only 1,2,5 and remaining should be print as it is
How can i add that.?

```sql
SUM(case when col not like '%,%' then col else 0 end )
```

I tried with this but remaining value it is making 0

I am not good at explaining i hope u will understand.

Comment: The *seems* like you are stating you want to store a list of delimited integer values. The answer is **don't**. Normalise your design.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether one entry in your table is literally a list of numbers separated by a comma or if these are 5 different entries. It's not clear at all what you are trying to do here. Please share your table schema, and some sample data for that table, and also desired results. I feel like we are only getting bits and pieces of a question.

Comment: Maybe you simply want to use the [ROUND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function? Or test `ROUND(x) = x`?

Comment: You want to sum the integer values only, so your desired result is 8? What is the column data type?

Answer (score 0):

Perhap you need the following?

```
SUM(case when col % 1 = 0 then col else 0 end)
```